# Database design for preset/custom choice questions

Tags: mysql, sql, database, forms, database-design

So I have a HTML form where users can answer single-choice questions either by checkboxing one of the three preset responses, or writing a custom answer of their own.

While this is obviously a many-to-many relationship, I still cannot find a proper way to design database tables so as to handle both types (TEXT and BOOLEAN). My current quick-and-dirty solution is to hard-code a specific choice_id in the junction table for custom answers. I'm looking for a better pattern for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the following tables:

**Table 1:`Question`**

```
  QuestionID (ID)
  QuestionText (Text)
```

**Table 2: `Question Response`**

```
  QuestionResponseId (ID)
  QuestionResponseTypeId (References Question Response Type)
  QuestionResponseDetailsId (References Question Response Details) - This should be used for text only values (Custom Answers)
  QuestionResponse (Boolean)
```

**Table 3: `Question Response Type`**

```
  QuestionResponseTypeId (Id)
  Description (Text)  -- Dictates if the answer is a boolean or a text field
```

**Table 4: `Question Response Details`**

```
   QuestionResponseDetailsId (Id)
   Description (Text) - Holds the text answer to the questions
```

When the following tables are populated you will have a structure that holds the question, the response of the question (text or boolean).

You could then filter on this to see only text based answers, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM QuestionResponse
INNER JOIN QuestionResponseDetails ON QuestionResponse.QuestionResponseDetailsId = QuestionResponseDetails.QuestionResponseDetailsId
WHERE QuestionResponse.QuestionResponseTypeId = 1
```

*Where 1 is a Text based answer and 2 is a Boolean based answer (From the Question Response Type Table)*

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would do something like this:

```
Table Answers:
question_id INT(11)
answer_id INT(11)
preset_answer TINYINT(1) //1, 2, 3 for three answers
custom_answer VARCHAR(255)
```